# False Smoke Alarm due to Interconnect/heat pump

Tags: wiring, smoke-detectors

In August, we had our gas furnace/electric ac replaced with a ducted heat pump (ECOER EODA18H-2436 with a matching air handler) in our condo built in 2009, and immediately started having false smoke alarms (they just alarm once, or they just chirp, and then stop).

We had our ducts professionally cleaned and replaced all of the smoke alarms with new ones.

They continued to false alarm when the heat pump (ac or heat) runs, but not when just the fan runs, and not if the smoke alarms are disconnected from the hardwire/interconnect.

We had an electrician replace all of the wiring harnesses and another new set of smoke alarms (BRK models). Problem still happens.

If we leave just the alarm furthest away from the indoor air handler and outdoor condenser and not near a duct with the others on battery backup and disconnected, only the connected one will trip.

That seems to indicate the problem is with the interconnect line.

The hvac company did not touch the wiring for the lightning/smoke alarm circuit. I measured the ac voltage to the smoke alarms and confirmed there's no voltage drop when the alarms trip.

I've already paid for two sets of new smoke alarms and a duct cleaning and the electrician and looking for advice on what to do next.

We can replace the entire interconnect line, but that means opening up ceilings, and there's no way to tell if that will solve the problem before doing it.

Or we can replace the six alarms with Nest devices that are wireless interconnected. I assume we can return them if it doesn't work.

Are there other options or other things to try? If I do replace with Nest, what can I do with 12 good but used smoke alarms?

Thanks!

EDIT:
Per suggestion by ThreePhaseEel below, I disconnected all of the interconnect lines but left the power to the alarms, assuming they wouldn't alarm. I was surprised that the alarm furthest away from the panel chirped and alarmed!

A [BRK article](https://www.brkelectronics.com/us/en/installer-corner/no-smoke-present-mro/) eludes to that:

> A large current load, like a vacuum cleaner, on the same circuit may cause nuisance alarms. This situation is aggravated if the load is located at the end of the wiring run, that is, electrically far away from the circuit box, and if the resistance of the wiring to the load is large. The voltage drop of the wiring to the load will be imposed on the interconnect wire thus causing the alarm to sound.
> But the new load (the heat pump) is on a different circuit (a different breaker).

Anyways, my family's patience grows thin for figuring out the cause so I'm trying out the Nest Protect alarm.

Comment: "what can I do with 12 good but used smoke alarms?" There are all sorts of on-line market places for used goods. If you have receipts showing just how new they are, you might get a reasonable percentage of the original price back. Unfortunately, that's a 2nd question (which doesn't fit well with our model here), and, as a stand-alone question, it doesn't fit well within this site.

Comment: Got it - thanks for the advice and the clarification about multiple questions! It sounds like used smoke alarms are more like used appliances that can be resold rather than used food that can't.

Comment: What make and model is the heat pump in question, and were the new smoke alarms the same model as the old ones?  Also, does a smoke alarm hooked up to AC power but not the interconnect line go off?  (Feel free to try putting a smoke alarm on a few different circuits for these tests.)

Comment: Good question - the heat pump is an ECOER EODA18H-2436 with a matching air handler. The smokes are the same manufacturer, but different models (the electrician installed smoke/CO combos which we didn't have before). Haven't tried an alarm hooked up to AC but not the interconnect - that's a good idea that I'll try. Thanks.

Comment: Good info, Peter, please [edit] that into your question so everyone will see it. Not everyone makes it through all the comments...

Comment: Sure thing, I edited, hopefully in what people expect. Thanks @ThreePhaseEel for the idea to disconnect the interconnect - even with it disconnected the furthest alarm still tripped, so it seems like something with the alarm's AC power?

Comment: @PeterYao -- one more test: can you try putting the heat pump into emergency heat mode, presuming your air handler is a typical North American type with resistive heatstrips in it, and seeing if that still sets off the smokes?  I'm thinking this is a case of the conducted-EMI gremlins...

Comment: Thanks for the thoughts, @ThreePhaseEel! You're right I'm in North America (MA), but the heat pump doesn't have a heatstrip in it... So far a Nest installed in the place where the alarm was tripping seems to have worked, so I'm rolling those out. Thanks again, I appreciate this community!